# Do all webcams use YUY2?

Tags: webcam, pixel, yuv

I've noticed that raw data from my webcam comes in the from of YUY2. Actually, this "raw data" is the input for an AVICAP callback, and I suppose that this is the actual data from the webcam.

Anyway, do all the webcams use YUY2 format, or should I expect different formats as well?

Answer (score 2):

YUY2/YUYV are probably most common.  I've also seen web cams that used MJPEG, but are less common.  Covering both of those will deal with a majority of non-network (Java or otherwise) style web cams.

Comment: Thanks. Would you happen to know the value of bmiHeader.biCompression for YUYV (too lazy to google it)?
* "non-network (Java or otherwise) style web cams." what do you mean by that?

Comment: Some cams use proprietary interfaces with Java or IP based stuff.  These are typically network web cams, rather than local USB cams.

Not sure on the first.  It would be a constant I would set and forget.  :)